# Pinned Tabs update notification

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, web

Is there any way to highlight pinned tabs in web browsers on new notifications like Gmail, Facebook or Twitter do? I think attached picture should explain what I mean.

I need solution for every browser.

[image]

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-highlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

Simple site's title change (with JavaScript) works on every web browser I wanted.

e.g. changing title in JavaScript:

```
document.title = baseTitle + " Ding Ding!";
```